# Grails Spring-Security: Grant authority under controller

Tags: grails, controller, spring-security, authorization

I'm new to grails. I usually grant authority to a user in bootstrap.groovy which looks like this:

```
def roleAdmin = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN') ?: new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(failOnError: true)

def userMe = User.findByUsername('admin') ?: new User(username: 'jhon',
                password: ('adminme'),enabled: true).save(failOnError:true)

UserRole.create userMe, roleAdmin
```

As you can see, this is done under bootstrap.groovy. Now I want to do it in a controller (ie. UserController) so that when I create a new user, it will also grant an authority. I was thinking it should be done under UserController's def save(), or maybe not.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what the question is.... the code that runs in bootstrap can also run in the controller...

Answer (score 0):

Hi.
If you want to create something by yourself, you need to create controllers for user and for role. But there is a plugin for it: [Spring Security UI](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-ui), which has already have all you need to manage.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you already have the [Spring-Security-Core](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core/) plug-in installed. This code should do what you are asking. You are going to want to have this code in a controller. I put mine in a controller I call AdminController which handles all my administrative tasks.

```
 def addUser= {

    def userRole = SecRole.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER') ?: new SecRole(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(failOnError: true)
    def adminRole = SecRole.findByAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN') ?: new SecRole(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(failOnError: true)

    /*create new user*/
    def user = SecUser.findByUsername("${params.username}") ?: new SecUser (
        username: params.username,
        password: params.password,
        enabled: true,
    ).save()

    /*Assign a user role*/
    if(params.accounttype.equals("User")){
        if (!user.authorities.contains(userRole)) {
            SecUserSecRole.create user, userRole
        }
    }
     /*Assign an admin role*/
    if(params.accounttype.equals("Admin")){
        if (!user.authorities.contains(adminRole)) {
            SecUserSecRole.create user, adminRole
        }
    }
}
```

On the gsp I made a select box allowing the admin to assign a user a particular role

```
<g:form controller="admin" action="addUser">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align ="right"><br>Username: <br></td>
    <td><br><g:textField name="username" value=""/><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right"><br>Password:  <br></td>
    <td><br><g:textField name="password" value=""/><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right"><br>Choose Role:<br></td>
    <td><br><g:select name="accounttype" from='${["User","Admin"]}'/><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><br><g:submitButton name="addUser" value="Add User" /></td></td>
  </tr>
```

Alter the code to suit your needs.